# How to resolve git status "Unmerged paths:"?

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, git-status

I merged branch `dog` into `animal`.  When I go to commit, I get the following:

```
Unmerged paths:
(use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
(use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution
both deleted:       ../public/images/originals/dog.ai
added by them:      ../public/images/original_files/dog.ai
```

I had different directory names and file names in each branch.  The `animal` branch has the changes that I want.

When I go to reset the head, it doesn't work.  And when I go to take any other git action (remove, checkout, etc), I get a `path not found` error.

What commands do I need to execute to resolve this?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

All you should need to do is:

```
# if the file in the right place isn't already committed:
git add <path to desired file>

# remove the "both deleted" file from the index:
git rm --cached ../public/images/originals/dog.ai

# commit the merge:
git commit
```

Comment: further explanation would come in handy

Comment: If you just want to get out of the merge mode without resolving anything, `git reset` as mentioned in another answer, is a better option.

Answer (score 83):

Another way of dealing with this situation if your files ARE already checked in, and your files have been merged (but not committed, so the merge conflicts are inserted into the file) is to run:

```
git reset
```

This will switch to HEAD, and tell git to forget any merge conflicts, and leave the working directory as is. Then you can edit the files in question (search for the "Updated upstream" notices). Once you've dealt with the conflicts, you can run

```
git add -p
```

which will allow you to interactively select which changes you want to add to the index. Once the index looks good (`git diff --cached`), you can commit, and then

```
git reset --hard
```

to destroy all the unwanted changes in your working directory.

Comment: What is  `"Updated upstream" notices`?

Comment: @takias: the markers in each file that look like: `<<<<<<< [branch] \n [content] \n ==== \n [content] \n [branch] >>>>>>>`. I think the format may have chanced slightly since I wrote this, but see https://wincent.com/wiki/Git_merge_conflict_cheatsheet for an example.

Comment: Will `git reset` remove untracked files?