# fatal: git-write-tree: error building trees

Tags: git

I did a `git pull` from a shared git repository, but something went really wrong, after I tried a `git revert`. Here is the situation now:

```
$ git stash
Source/MediaStorageAndFileFormat/gdcmImageCodec.cxx: needs merge
Source/MediaStorageAndFileFormat/gdcmJPEGLSCodec.cxx: needs merge
Source/MediaStorageAndFileFormat/gdcmPNMCodec.cxx: needs merge
Testing/Source/DataStructureAndEncodingDefinition/Cxx/TestDS.cxx: needs merge
Utilities/socketxx/socket++/sockstream.cpp: needs merge
Source/MediaStorageAndFileFormat/gdcmImageCodec.cxx: needs merge
Source/MediaStorageAndFileFormat/gdcmJPEGLSCodec.cxx: needs merge
Source/MediaStorageAndFileFormat/gdcmPNMCodec.cxx: needs merge
Testing/Source/DataStructureAndEncodingDefinition/Cxx/TestDS.cxx: needs merge
Utilities/socketxx/socket++/sockstream.cpp: needs merge
Source/MediaStorageAndFileFormat/gdcmImageCodec.cxx: unmerged (2aafac967c35fa4e77c3086b83a3c102939ad168)
Source/MediaStorageAndFileFormat/gdcmImageCodec.cxx: unmerged (78cc95e8bae85bf8345a7793676e878e83df167b)
Source/MediaStorageAndFileFormat/gdcmImageCodec.cxx: unmerged (2524db713fbde0d7ebd86bfe2afc4b4d7d48db33)
Source/MediaStorageAndFileFormat/gdcmJPEGLSCodec.cxx: unmerged (4bb4ba78973091eaa854b03c6ce24e8f4af9e7cc)
Source/MediaStorageAndFileFormat/gdcmJPEGLSCodec.cxx: unmerged (ad0982b8b8b4c4fef23e69bbb639ca6d0cd98dd8)
Source/MediaStorageAndFileFormat/gdcmJPEGLSCodec.cxx: unmerged (4868371b7218c6e007fb6c582ad4ab226167a80a)
Source/MediaStorageAndFileFormat/gdcmPNMCodec.cxx: unmerged (f7a1b386b5b13b8fa8b6a31ce1258d2d5e5b13c5)
Source/MediaStorageAndFileFormat/gdcmPNMCodec.cxx: unmerged (6ce299c416fbb3bb60e11ef1e54962ffd3449a4c)
Source/MediaStorageAndFileFormat/gdcmPNMCodec.cxx: unmerged (75c8043a60a56a1130a34cdbd91d130bc9343c1c)
Testing/Source/DataStructureAndEncodingDefinition/Cxx/TestDS.cxx: unmerged (79c2843f2649ea9c87fa57662dafd899a5fa39ee)
...
fatal: git-write-tree: error building trees
Cannot save the current index state
```

Is there a way to reset all that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 609, accepted):

Use

```bash
git reset --mixed
```

instead of  `git reset --hard`. You will not lose any changes.

Comment: Note that the `--mixed` argument is also `git reset`'s default behavior, when not given an argument. [manpage](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reset.html) for reference.

Comment: Valid answer, but would be nice to have an explanation for what happened and why this was necessary.

Comment: @mmigdol Yeah - I'd like to see an explanation of why `git reset` with the (default) `--mixed` option is appropriate and effective here also. According to [merge - Git unmerged path issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207029/git-unmerged-path-issue): **This will switch to HEAD, and tell git to forget any merge conflicts, and leave the working directory as is.**  heracek, is that what's going on?

Comment: Doesn't work. I get `git: 'reset--mixed' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`

Comment: @writofmandamus Months late, but note the space between reset and the hyphens.

Comment: FWIW I ran into this issue when I was doing `git stash`. Doing `git reset --mixed` resolved it.

Answer (score 57):

This worked for me:

Do

```
$ git status
```

And check if you have `Unmerged paths`

```
# Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#   (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)
#
#   both modified:      app/assets/images/logo.png
#   both modified:      app/models/laundry.rb
```

Fix them with `git add` to each of them and try `git stash` again.

```
git add app/assets/images/logo.png
```

Comment: This worked for me. git reset --mixed may be better than world peace, but without some explanation of what it does, I ain't touching it. In my case, there was a collision in an earlier pull that I didn't notice. The stash failed because of the unresolved pull.

Comment: I don't understand this strategy any better than `git reset --mixed`, but it worked, and seemed like a better fit for my case because I got the error after `git stash` rather than `git revert`.

Comment: An *unmerged* path means you have run ```git merge```, or the equivalent of git merge, and it tried to merge two different sets of changes to that file, but failed.

Comment: This worked for me, too, after attempting to do a ```git stash```.  I had to do a ```git add <file>``` first, then the stash succeeded.

Answer (score 11):

To follow up on malat's response, you can avoid losing changes by creating a patch and reapply it at a later time.

```
git diff --no-prefix > patch.txt
patch -p0 < patch.txt
```

Store your patch outside the repository folder for safety.

Comment: This gave me: SDGL132d9f4b4:glitch-common dstromberg$ patch -p0 < /tmp/patch.txt 
patch: **** Only garbage was found in the patch input.

Comment: I think you should `mv` the patch back again into the directory where you created it from. 1. `git diff` 2. `mv patch.txt /tmp`3. `git stash` 4. `mv /tmp/patch.txt .` 5. `patch -p0`

Answer (score 10):

I used:

```
 git reset --hard
```

I lost some changes, but this is ok.

Comment: Just a note: [`git revert`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-revert.html) attempts to merge changes from the past; you have correctly used `git reset` to simply rewind the clock. It is unfortunate that `git stash` does not work with merge conflicts.

Comment: If  you lose changes, this is not a fix ;)

Answer (score 5):

maybe there are some unmerged paths in your git repository that you have to resolve before stashing.

Comment: This helped me so I will give it a +1. But I put a more extended answer.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when trying to **merge** another branch. The merge failed with `fatal: git-write-tree: error building trees` and complained about a different file that had nothing to do with the merge. My branch then contained the files it had tried to merge, as uncommitted changes.

I cleared the changes it had attempted to merge, then removed the problem file and rebuilt the hash:

```
git reset --hard;

git rm --cache problem_file.txt;

git hash-object -w problem_file.txt;
```

The merge then worked.

Answer (score -1):

This happened for me when I was trying to stash my changes, but then my changes had **conflicts** with my branch's current state.

So I did `git reset --mixed` and then resolved the git conflict and stashed again.