# Undo git stash pop that results in merge conflict

Tags: git, git-stash

I began making changes to my codebase, not realizing I was on an old topic branch. To transfer them, I wanted to stash them and then apply them to a new branch off of master. I used `git stash pop` to transfer work-in-progress changes to this new branch, forgetting that I hadn't pulled new changes into master before creating the new branch. This resulted in a bunch of merge conflicts and loss of a clean stash of my changes (since I used pop).

Once I recreate the new branch correctly, how I can I recover my stashed changes to apply them properly?

Comment: Git is smart enough not to drop a stash if it doesn't apply cleanly

Comment: ... and knowing that your stash is still on the `git stash list`, be free to use `git reset --hard`. i.e. when you stash-poped on the wrong branch and your conflict is obvious.

Comment: Here's a duplicate question with a far simpler resolution to stash pop conflicts with a limited number of files affected https://stackoverflow.com/a/60348183/5440638

Answer (score 1078, accepted):

As it turns out, Git is smart enough not to drop a stash if it doesn't apply cleanly. I was able to get to the desired state with the following steps:

1. To unstage the merge conflicts: `git reset HEAD .` (note the trailing dot)
2. To save the conflicted merge (just in case): `git stash`
3. To return to master: `git checkout master`
4. To pull latest changes: `git fetch upstream; git merge upstream/master`
5. To correct my new branch: `git checkout new-branch; git rebase master`
6. To apply the correct stashed changes (now 2nd on the stack): `git stash apply stash@{1}`

Comment: Excellent thanks! #6 is really the answer I was looking for. Could add a `git stash drop` as the last step to get rid of the unwanted stash from #2.

Comment: #2 will not work if there are unmerged paths, it will instead output the error described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483213/fatal-git-write-tree-error-building-trees

Comment: Not totally true--Git will keep the stash in the stash list if it failed to apply cleanly. See these docs about `git stash pop`: "Applying the state can fail with conflicts; in this case, it is not removed from the stash list. You need to resolve the conflicts by hand and call `git stash drop` manually afterwards." (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)

Comment: This doesn't work properly.  :-(  It undid the changes but it left a bunch of noise in my files like: `<<<<<<< Updated upstream` `>>>>>>> Stashed changes`

Comment: @Jez You might try `git checkout -- .` to get back to a clean state. Or `git stash`, if you're worried you might possibly lose something important.

Comment: @call-me This is something I think people should actually do more often! Notice how the "Ask a question" form has a checkbox that let's you answer your own question in the same form :). This happens to me sometimes when I'm in the process of authoring a question that is stumping me, but in trying to tune the question to be good for StackOverflow, I end up figuring out the solution. This was a while ago, so I don't remember if that was the case here, but I'm guessing that's what happened.

Comment: @acjay Exactly! Sometimes I come to Stackoverflow to write a question when I'm stuck because the process of making sure I write a good question often helps me answer it myself (or even just find the correct question) :)

Comment: Some shells need additional quotes for #6: git stash apply 'stash@{1}', otherwise you get the error: unknown option: -encodedCommand

Comment: this answer is unnecessarily complex because it's involving branches, and they were not mentioned in the question

Comment: Step 1.5) `git add --all`

Comment: Step 4 could also be `git pull origin master`. Does the same, but is a bit more concise

Answer (score 519):

Luckily `git stash pop` does **not** change the stash in the case of a conflict!

So nothing, to worry about, just clean up your code and try it again.

Say your codebase was clean before, you could go back to that state with: `git checkout -f`
Then do the stuff you forgot, e.g. `git merge missing-branch`
After that just fire `git stash pop` again and you get the **same** stash, that conflicted before.

Keep in mind: The stash is safe, however, **uncommitted** changes in the working directory are of course not. They can get messed up.

Comment: What I understand is that you can simply cleanup and pop again, but you can't *undo* it. If the pop gets mixed with other uncommitted changes, then you have to clean up manually.

Comment: This is a very simple solution and worked great for me. It assumes that you can revert everything that has changed locally (there were no changes before/after the stash was popped) which I think works for most situations.

If you needed to save some additional changes that happened before realizing that this was a problem, you should be able to commit those files before forcing a checkout in most cases.

Comment: This was not the case for me.  I called `git stash pop` it attempted to auto-merge, conflicted, and kept it.

Comment: @TrevorHickey The point of this answer was that the stash stays as it is in case of a conflict, that you can call `git stash pop` as often you need until it ends without a conflict. So after your conflict, yes, the working directory is in mess, however, you can clean it up and call `git stash pop` again.

Comment: this command to undo last stash apply is very useful: `git checkout -f` !

Comment: what does git checkout -f mean?

Comment: I was partially wrong. The stash that had some of my work was @1, not pop (not sure why exactly). However, the new files weren't included in that stash. I'm sure I did something more convoluted that messed this up.

Comment: `git checkout -f branchname` means "checkout branchname, and f = force, meaning I know there are uncommitted changes where I am right now, I don't care just dump everything.  Since `git stash pop` doesn't actually "pop" if there are conflicts, I was able to do the force checkout and then `git stash pop` again on the correct branch. Easy peasy.

Comment: This is the correct answer. One thing that I always do after I fix all the conflicts is `git stash drop` to get rid of the saved stash that had the conflicts.

Answer (score 134):

The simplest command, it works everywhere including `git stash pop`, `git merge` etc.

But careful! You'll lose all changes on untracked files. Tracked files stays intact

```
git reset --merge
```

Comment: Careful here! You'll lose all changes on untracked files.

Comment: And you'll lose all changes on staged, tracked files too it seems.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed, since I've had changes in tracked files, so I didn't want a hard reset, and they were left in place.

Comment: This is dangerous! I ran this after running `git stash pop` while I already had files indexed, and I lost all of my indexed files!

Comment: TOO BAD I DIDNT RESEARCH WHAT UNTRACKED FILES WERE BEFOREHAND!!!!  Good Friggin grief!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 47):

Instructions here are a little complicated so I'm going to offer something more straightforward:

1. `git reset HEAD --hard` Abandon all changes to the current branch
2. `...` Perform intermediary work as necessary
3. `git stash pop` Re-pop the stash again at a later date when you're ready

Answer (score 36):

```
git checkout -f
```

must work, if your previous state is clean.

CAUTION: Beware–you'll lose all untracked changes to your files.

Comment: Beware–you'll lose all untracked changes to your files.

Comment: well this removed some of my tracked, staged, but not committed changes!

Answer (score 2):

If you're like me and had **unstaged changes that you want to preserve**, you can avoid losing that work by checking out a known stable version of each individual file from the `stash`. Hopefully those files are different than the ones you were working on. Also, this is why we use small commits as we go, dumb dumb.

```bash
git checkout main -- <file_with_conflicts>
```