# Git stash failed: bad address

Tags: git

C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-stash: line 127: D:/project/MyApplication/.git/.git-stash.86404-stagenames: Bad address
Cannot save the current worktree state

Comment: May you provide more information? What does the worktree look like? `git status` output? etc

Comment: @evolutionxbox The work tree just has few changes with the java files.

Comment: Have a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483213/fatal-git-write-tree-error-building-trees