# Unable to git add, remove, also there is no file in related location. What should I do?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

File not showing on related location.

```
Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
#
#       added by them:      app/etc/ local.xml~
#
```

Comment: Try the below solution provided
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207029/git-unmerged-path-issue

Comment: Are you sure this command "git rm --cached ../public/images/originals/dog.ai" command is safe my data which is in git folder not affected

Comment: URL is to to replaced by your own URL and just read about git rm--cached

Comment: Okay thank you I will check it. is it possible to remove file from git index I think this file saved in git index. What you think.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve merge conflicts in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-to-resolve-merge-conflicts-in-git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you noted that there's a space at the beginning of the file name? Execute one of the following:

`git add "app/etc/ local.xml~"`

Or

`git rm "app/etc/ local.xml~"`

Comment: File is not exist there. I checked.