# Merging changes from master into local custom branch

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a Gitlab repo with several project folders into a master branch. This repo is shared among a few developers.
A few days ago, I created a custom branch on which I added a new project folder.
Later a remote developer updated the master branch, deleting several project folders and adding a new one called `project1`.
Now I would need to integrate `project1` folder into my local custom branch.

What I tried so far, is this:

```
1. git checkout master
2. git pull origin master
3. git checkout custom
4. git merge master
```

Following conflicts are showing up:

```
CONFLICT (rename/delete): gatsby-setup/cloud/ansible.cfg renamed to gatsby-env-setup/ansible.cfg in HEAD, but deleted in master.
CONFLICT (rename/delete): gatsby-setup/cloud/roles/nginx/handlers/main.yml renamed to gatsby-env-setup/roles/nginx/handlers/main.yml in HEAD, but deleted in master.
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Running a git status command, I see the following output:

```
Changes to be committed:
    deleted:    adduser-devops/README.md
    deleted:    adduser-devops/ansible.cfg
    deleted:    adduser-devops/group_vars/all.yml
        .....................

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
    deleted by them: gatsby-env-setup/ansible.cfg
    deleted by them: gatsby-env-setup/roles/nginx/handlers/main.yml
```

Tried to open my local repo into Visual Studio code, and I noticed that several project folders have been deleted.

I don't want to have a replica of master branch, I need to keep my local folders.
All I need is to integrate the `project1` folder into my local custom branch

To cancel merge I ran `git merge --abort`

What is the right command I should run to manage this?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just added the question!

Comment: If you need the projects that were removed, then you cannot use the branch that was made by the remote developer. If you still need the project added by that developer, then that developer probably made a mistake that they removed the other projects at the same time. There is no simple, out-of-the-box Git command that can help.

Answer (score 1):

Following instructions here: [How to resolve git status "Unmerged paths:"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207029/how-to-resolve-git-status-unmerged-paths) I ran `git add .` `git commit` and then `git push origin custom_branch`.
`git status` doesn't show any errors.
However I lost my local folders...

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on a local branch, nobody else will push changes to that one and you need to add new commits from a branch where you are going to do a merge once you finished working there, you might need to use [git rebase instead of git merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666089/whats-the-difference-between-git-merge-and-git-rebase#:%7E:text=Reading%20the%20official%20Git%20manual,it%20happened%2C%20rebase%20rewrites%20it.)